# ManagedBeans not autodiscovered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a strange behaviour using JSF: my classes annotated with @Managedbean are not visible / available in the view and I can' t call them through EL.

Then I created a faces-config.xml file and explicitly declared the managed beans and in this way they can be called.

What is the problem for which they aren' t auto discovered?

This is my relevant code:

The web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The managed Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean
public class LanguagesCountryLocaleController {

    public String sayHello(){ 
        return "Just to make it short!"; 
    }
}
```

The faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>languagesCountryLocaleController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.fry.starter.commands.manager.content.LanguagesCountryLocaleController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean> 

</faces-config>
```

and the call in the  xhtml file:

```
#{languagesCountryLocaleController.sayHello()}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need one of both, declare them at faces-config or annotate with `@ManagedBean`. In case using annotations don't forget to provide the scope annotation and also to include at least an empty faces-config.xml file.

Comment: Make sure to rightfully mapped the FacesServlet from JSF for your XHTML files in your web.xml. Apart from that, choose only one configuration for your managed beans: using annotations or using faces-config.xml configuration, IMO I would use the former over the latter.

Comment: I have added the web.xml (the related mapped part) to the problem description for completness.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Problem suggests it's actually not 2.2.